# Unknown iOS Chrome Javascript error - fillForm

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, browser, autofill

Through a bug reporting framework, I've received a number of javascript errors coming from Chrome on iOS (multiple users). I suspect they have to do with Chrome's autofill.

The error is:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'c.addEventListener')
```

Where `c` varies (probably due to our script minification).

The stack trace indicates it's not coming from our script, but from somewhere on the page

```
index.html:11   fillForm    
index.html:1    global code
```

Additionally, it appears that the last thing the user does is click on an `input` element.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone know what's causing this error or how to prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

This type of errors occurs when you try to execute method on null object. In your situation 'c' is null. That's why you have this error. If this string of code is yours (c.addEventListner), then simply add check for null and execute code if it's not null. If this part is from the framework, then you should check why your modifications makes it null. If not, fill bug report to framework development team.

Comment: The problem is that the error and stack trace doesn't come from a framework I'm using or my code. I suspect it's coming from Chrome itself.